# Print firebase schema from class

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to print the firebase schema from POJOs?

the question might look a bit awkward, but since i've no tool to design firebase database model (what a shame google) i do straight design the pojos itself and as it grow big gets more difficult to "vizualise" the whole structure and possible gaps or maybe redundant fields

would be good to have a way to print out the schema and see it

by schame i mean like one instance of the whole database with dumb data

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in tool in the Firebase platform to print a schema for your Realtime Database based on the Java classes.

If you're considering using Cloud Firestore, there *is* a tool to generate security rules from protobuf definitions. See https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/protobuf-rules-gen